# Silverlight navigation with the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, silverlight-5.0

I followed Robert Garfoot's blog ["Silverlight Navigation With the MVVM Pattern"](http://garfoot.com/blog/2010/09/silverlight-navigation-with-the-mvvm-pattern/).

It allows you to take the navigation handling from the page's code-behind in a vary elegant way.

He makes Navigate, GoBack and GoForward available to your ViewModel, so you can leave the code-behind free of navigation code.

It works beautiful.

**But there are some events (Navigated, Navigating, NavigationFailed among others) that I'd like to have access to from the ViewModel.
I don't know how to do it. It's a matter of using interfaces and mastering c#.**

Excuse me if it's somewhat long but I'll try to make it brief:

I'll put all this classes in a namespace called LibrariesSL.MVVMNavigation:

He creates a INavigationService interface:

```
public interface INavigationService {
    void NavigateTo(string url);
    void GoBack();
    void GoForward();
}
```

The a NavigationService class:

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService {
    private readonly System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService _navigationService;
    public NavigationService(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService navigationService) {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public void NavigateTo(string url) {
        _navigationService.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public void GoBack() {
       ...
    }

    public void GoForward() {
       ...
    }
}
```

Then a INavigable interface that will be used to extend the ViewModel:

```
public interface INavigable {
    INavigationService NavigationService { get; set; }
}
```

In the ViewModel we just inherit and use it:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : ViewModelsBase, INavigable {

   MyDomainContext _Context = new MyDomainContext ();
   ...

   ...

  public void OnShowCustomer(object param) {
      int selectedCustomerID = SelectedCustomer.CustomerID;
      // Here we perform navigation
      NavigationService.NavigateTo(string.Format("/CustomerDetails?CustomerID={0}", 
                                                                  selectedCustomerID));
  }


   #region INavigable

   public INavigationService NavigationService { get; set; }

   #endregion
```

We have to also make a Dependency Property that's appended to the View:

```
public static class Navigator {
    public static INavigable GetSource(DependencyObject obj) {
        return (INavigable)obj.GetValue(SourceProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(INavigable), typeof(Navigator), 
                                         new PropertyMetadata(OnSourceChanged));

    private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        Page page = (Page)d;
        page.Loaded += PageLoaded;
    }

    private static void PageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Page page = (Page)sender;
        INavigable navSource = GetSource(page);
        if (navSource != null) {
            navSource.NavigationService = new NavigationService(page.NavigationService);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the view we do this:

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="UsingQueryStrings.Views.Customers" 
      ...
      xmlns:MVVMNavigation="clr-namespace:LibrariesSL.MVVMNavigation"
      MVVMNavigation:Navigator.Source="{Binding}"
 >
```

**I'd like to have access to the events Navigated, Navigating and NavigationFailed present in System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.**

Comment: Can't you just duplicate these events on your NavigationService?

Comment: Yes, those events get fired in the NavigationService, but what if I'm reusing the ViewModel with several Views, the response to those events could be different depending on the view. I want to do everything from the ViewModel.

Comment: So you want your ViewModel to behave differently based on what View is interacting with it?

Comment: Sounds like you need more than one ViewModel.

Comment: There's one Navigation Service, and there are several ViewModels, each should make their own implementation of thos events